# Grails Resources - cannot add r.script in layout?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I made a script that loads content based on the current request locale. Something like

```
class ScriptsTagLib {
  static namespace = "my"
  def loadLangInfo = { attrs ->
    Locale locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
    r.script() {
      out << '$(function(){ loadLangInfo("'+locale.language+'") });'
    }
  }
}
```

If I add this in my layout, the page throws an error:

> Error evaluating expression [my.loadLangInfo()] on line [6]: Cannot
>   add module [-page-fragments-] which requires disposition [defer] to
>   this request -  that disposition has already been rendered.
>
> Error 2012-11-19 15:13:54,801 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR
>   [Tomcat].[localhost]  - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500,
>   location=/grails-errorhandler] Message:
>   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: The character encoding [null] is
>   not supported

But if I add this tag in my page instead of the layout, the page is rendered with success.

It's not possible to add `r.script()` to a layout?

**EDIT:** The problem is really with resources in the layout. Another example that fails is:

```
<g:layoutHead/>
<r:script>
$(function(){ });
</r:script>
<r:layoutResources />
```

**EDIT 2:** More info about the context

- Grails 2.0.4
- Resources 1.2.RC2

Also, it's a layout inside a plugin, and not one app.

Not tested in Grails 2.1, but will do that.

**EDIT 3**:

Just tested now, with `Grails 2.1.1` and `Grails 2.0.4` new fresh **plugin projects**, and the script tag in the layout is ignored!

./views/layout/test.gsp -> Script ignored

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Insoft4 UI Plugin"/></title>
        <g:layoutHead/>

        <r:layoutResources />
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <r:script disposition="defer">
            alert('layout!');
        </r:script>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

./views/index.gsp -> Script OK

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Teste</title>
        <meta name="layout" content="teste" />
                <r:script disposition="defer">
            alert('index!');
        </r:script>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing this index!</h1>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that the problem occurs when you have declared `<r:layoutResources />` in both, layout and page and you try to add a script in the layout.

To correct I removed the `layoutResources` from every view, leaving just in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add tag before the last r:layoutResources on the layout.

Comment: loadLangInfo is just a javascript function. The problem is with resources, see my edit.

Comment: Then where and how "page-fragments" module is defined/added?

Comment: page-fragments seems to be the name used by resources for script code that you add in `r:script`, I don't have any module named with this. Also updated the question with my tests, it seems that scripts in a plugin layout are ignored by resources...